# my basic authentication web api not showing authentication pop up in any browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webapi

i want to show username password for authenticate the user.where to change it to get authentication pop up.below is the webapi.config file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
```

api controller

```
[BasicAuthentication]
[Route("Reactor")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string username = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: Where do you host your application? IIISExpress or regular IIS?

Comment: i have hosted in IIS 8, windows 2012 R2

Comment: So you should enable at least both auth types at IIS server: anonymous and basic. Check this first.